# Passing 8-bytes value between Assembly & C functions through the stack

Tags: c, assembly, x86, stack, calling-convention

I try to pass three parameters from fasm code to c function:

```
push ebx
push eax
push esi
push edx
call _kernel_main

void kernel_main(uint8 boot_disk_id, void *memory_map, uint64 first_file_sector_number)
```

What I expect:

- **boot_disk_id** gets **edx** data, it's low byte
- **memory_map** gets **esi** data,
- **first_file_sector_number** gets 8-bytes value, **eax** - upper 4 bytes, **ebx**- low 4 bytes

[image]

Let's say **ebx** contains **0x0** and **eax** contains **0x2** so first_file_sector_number will get value **0x2**,

when I change position ebx and eax like that:

```
push eax
push ebx
push esi
push edx
call _kernel_main
```

I expect first_file_sector_number will contain 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000**1**0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000, that is **0x200000000**
but it contains **0x0**.

Could you please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you add objdump result of the related part of the executable to the question. I think stack alignment or the unknown sized pointer at the second parameter may cause the problem.

Comment: x86 is little-endian so `eax` will correspond to the low (least-significant) bytes of `first_file_sector_number`.  I think you said it two different ways.  Likewise `boot_disk_id` will be in the low byte of the stack slot corresponding to `edx`; you have it in the high two bytes in your diagram.

Comment: Yes, the diagram is drawn incorrectly. With little endianness taken into account (so not 0x200000000), you still shouldn't be getting 0x0 instead of 0x200000, are you printing it correctly?

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the diagram and I'm still excpecting 0x200000000 instead of 0.

Comment: This is objdump result. Is this enough? Honeslty I use this tool first time. https://i.gyazo.com/ccc5c87da738b4b913ddf86ea5fb5776.png

Comment: well in the first case, on the new diagram, the value of `first_file_sector_number` is 0x200000000 and in the swapped case it is 0x2

Comment: That function disassembly is not particularly useful because it's not showing the functions that are being called or their signatures. The issue is clearly in how you are printing the value of the sector, you must be printing it as 32 bits

Comment: I thought it had been the source of my issue so I did right shift but I had the same result.

Comment: In order to make things simpler, you might keep only the print function in `kernel_main` and comment out everything else. Compile without any optimization and use `objdump -D [yourexecname]`. Then, you may show us the disassembled functions (kernel_main, your print function, and the function you called kernel_main in it)